SVG badge with tick inside
I am trying to implement svg badge, and inside badge trying to add tick, but not able to do it. Below image is what I able to do.

What I am trying to do it, like below image.

attached is the code which is tried so far. Is there any way I can accomplish it in SVG.


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256" xml:space="preserve">

<defs>
</defs>
<g style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: none; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(1.4065934065934016 1.4065934065934016) scale(2.81 2.81)" >
    <path d="M 44.759 63.847 L 56.954 90 l 9.909 -9.079 l 13.325 -1.755 L 68.323 53.721 c -9.609 -0.082 -17.439 3.046 -23.082 10.126" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(237,99,98); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) " stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path d="M 45.241 63.847 L 33.046 90 l -9.909 -9.079 L 9.812 79.166 l 11.865 -25.445 C 33.52 52.826 41.539 56.026 45.241 63.847 z" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(233,84,84); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) " stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path d="M 45 63.847 c 17.631 0 31.923 -14.293 31.923 -31.923 S 62.631 0 45 0 C 34.483 21.782 33.645 43.104 45 63.847 z" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,204,91); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) " stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path d="M 45 63.847 c -17.631 0 -31.923 -14.293 -31.923 -31.923 S 27.369 0 45 0 v 63.814" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(253,188,75); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) " stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path d="M 38.778 54.411 c -0.092 0 -0.186 -0.013 -0.279 -0.039 C 26.122 50.786 18.967 37.8 22.552 25.422 c 0.153 -0.531 0.707 -0.836 1.239 -0.682 c 0.53 0.153 0.836 0.708 0.682 1.239 c -3.277 11.318 3.264 23.193 14.583 26.471 c 0.53 0.154 0.836 0.709 0.682 1.239 C 39.611 54.127 39.211 54.411 38.778 54.411 z" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(236,153,34); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) " stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path d="M 66.487 39.146 c -0.092 0 -0.186 -0.013 -0.278 -0.04 c -0.53 -0.154 -0.836 -0.708 -0.683 -1.239 c 1.589 -5.483 0.946 -11.256 -1.808 -16.256 c -2.755 -5 -7.291 -8.628 -12.774 -10.216 c -0.53 -0.153 -0.836 -0.708 -0.683 -1.239 c 0.154 -0.53 0.708 -0.835 1.239 -0.682 c 5.996 1.736 10.957 5.704 13.969 11.172 c 3.013 5.468 3.715 11.781 1.979 17.777 C 67.321 38.862 66.922 39.146 66.487 39.146 z" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(236,153,34); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"/>
    <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M 20.285 2l-11.285 11.567-5.286-5.011-3.714 3.716 9 8.728 15-15.285z" style="/* stroke: none; *//* stroke-width: 1; *//* stroke-dasharray: none; *//* stroke-linecap: butt; *//* stroke-linejoin: miter; *//* stroke-miterlimit: 10; */fill: rgb(236,153,34);/* stroke-miterlimit: inherit; *//* fill-rule: nonzero; *//* opacity: 1; *//* padding: 9px; */" transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) " stroke-linecap="round"/>
</g>
</svg>




identify which d-path is the tick, the first M is the x,y position. eg. M 20.285 2

You can also open your SVGs in an vector graphic editor like inkscape and align these elements visually. It's often way easier to do this in a GUI

You need to move the path, either by editing it in a tool like SvgPathEditor or use the transform attribute to move it.
In the example I did a redraw of the entire thing. Notice that some of the elements are grouped (<g>) and moved together (like transform="translate(128 91)"). This makes each element simpler (like the circles being place as default in 0,0).


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="256" height="256"
  viewBox="0 0 256 256">
  <g transform="translate(128 91)">
    <g transform="translate(0 6)">
      <path d="M -36 0 V 90 L 0 78 L 36 90 V 0 Z" fill="rgb(233,84,84)"
        transform="rotate(25) translate(0 67)" />
      <path d="M -36 0 V 90 L 0 78 L 36 90 V 0 Z" fill="rgb(237,99,98)"
        transform="rotate(-25) translate(0 67)" />
    </g>
    <circle r="90" fill="rgb(253,188,75)" />
    <path d="M 0 -90 a 1 1 0 1 1 0 180 Z" fill="rgb(255,204,91)" />
    <circle r="62" stroke="rgb(236,153,34)" stroke-width="5"
      stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(-76)" fill="none"
      stroke-dasharray="10 10" pathLength="40" />
    <path d="M 18 -26 Q 30 -38 33 -23 Q 36 -11 30 -5 L -6 31
      Q -12 37 -18 31 L -36 13 Q -42 7 -36 -8 Q -33 -17 -18 -2
      L -15 1 Q -12 4 -9 1 Z" fill="rgb(236,153,34)" />
  </g>
</svg>



